# Characteristic function of measurable sets is always measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. I already know that $A\subset \Omega$ is measurable if and only if $\mathbb{1}_{A}$ is $\langle \mathcal{F},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\rangle$-measurable (where $\mathbb{1}_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$ and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$).

What I want to know is if, for any $A\in \mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{1}_A:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is $\langle \mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}\rangle$-measurable regardless of which $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ is being used on $\mathbb{R}$.

Given $E\in \mathcal{G}$, we can see that $(\mathbb{1}_A)^{-1}(E)$ is always in $\mathcal{F}$:
$$(\mathbb{1}_A)^{-1}(E)=\begin{cases} A & 1\in E,0\notin E\\ A^c & 1\notin E, 0\in E\\ \Omega & 1\in E, 0\in E\\ \emptyset & 1\notin E, 0\notin E \end{cases}$$

So my guess would be that the above statment is true; however, I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: I don't see any error in your reasoning.

Comment: Neither do I. To make things more complicated. If $f:X\to Y$ is a function, then for each $A\subseteq Y$, we have $f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(f(X)\cap A)$. So only the induced $\sigma$-algebra on $\{0,1\}$ matters. One of those is trivial and makes every function measurable, the other one coincides with the $\sigma$-algebra induced on $\{0,1\}$ by the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Very interesting! Thanks a lot!